# full hard drive need to move files centos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I need to download a directory from one server and place it into it's successor. The trouble is, the server is 97% full. So taring the files isn't an option. I need a method to transfer about 60 gigs from one server to another through ssh. 
The predecessor is centos and the successor is ubuntu.

Comment: Taring is always an option, especially if redirected to the ssh session. `tar zcf - /old/path | ssh user@host.tld "tar xzf - -C /final/path"`

Comment: But am I going to need 60 gigs of hard drive space?

Comment: No, archived and compressed stream will be streamed away to the new host. What you really need - is the stable reliable connection between hosts. And fast indeed.

Comment: Oh no. It denied me because it uses rsa ssh keys.

Comment: is there a way to swap the servers? I'm having issues getting into one server from the other but not the other way around

Comment: You can use rsync and do a push or pull depending on which direction your ssh keys are working.

Comment: You can change the roles. `ssh user@oldhost.tld "tar zсf - /old/path" | tar zxf - /new/path` But you have to test that with some small dir to be sure everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `rsync` with archive and compression enabled?
Something like this on the new server:

```
rsync -avz oldserver.domain:/path/to/dir  /path/to/new/dir
```

If `rsync` got interrupted for any reason (link dropped, alien attack, etc...), or some files got updated on the old server after copying, you can always re-run rsync with the update option `u` to resume the operation:

```
rsync -avuz oldserver.domain:/path/to/dir  /path/to/new/dir
```

(Make sure to check the manual page for more information `man rsync` )

Comment: I don't think rsync is the right solution. Does it send the files individually? is that why rsync is 3 times slower then tar zcf - ?